# Declare a "list" of constant in a class

Tags: c++, class, constants, c++03

I would like to create a list of constant within my class but I don't know how tto do it properly.

First I tried to but it in an Enum like that:

```
class CMyClass{

public:
enum EKeyword
{
  E_PARAM1 = "myString1",
  E_PARAM2 = "myString2",
  ...
};
```

but it seems that it is not possible (-> error C2057: expected constant expression)

I know that I could just declare one by one each of my constant with a #define or using "static const ..." declaration but I like the use of : EKeyword.E_PARAM1 to get my string and I don't want to set those constants global.

Any recommandations ?

Comment: What is the use case for this?

Comment: I'm creating a list of keyword that I will looking for in a file and then exchange the keyword with its value. ex: find the keyword "$temperature" -> replace the word with "28°C"

Comment: "I'm not working with c++11" - You know, it'd be nice to know such constraints *before the fact*.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make an `enum` with a string representation in c++. You will need a list of strings. If you wan't to force them to be referenced inside a structure (like an `enum class`) add them to a struct:

```
class CMyClass {
public: 
    struct EKeyword {
        static constexpr char const* PARAM_1 = "myString1";
        ...
        private:
           EKeyword(); // Disables the ability to construct an EKeyword struct.

    };
...
```

Then use within the class will be like:

```
EKeyword::PARAM_1
```

and outside the class will be:

```
CMyClass::EKeyword::PARAM_1
```

---

If you are limited to `c++03` you will need to create the string values in a cpp file:

```
// .hpp
class CMyClass {
 ...
 struct EKeyword {
    static char const* PARAM_1;
    ...

// .cpp
char const* CMyClass::EKeyword::PARAM_1 = "myString1";
```

[Here is a live example.](https://ideone.com/DWH6Gy)

Comment: Better. I like the scoping idea. +1

Comment: @StoryTeller Yeah, it's nice. We use it for enumerations as well because we are still stuck in c++03 land.

Comment: Why should I use constexpr instead of const ?

Comment: @Thieuma If you wan't to use this definition in other `constexpr` functions or definitions then you need it to be.

Comment: I will have to read more about constexpr to understand but it seems only available since c++11. That I'm not working on.

Comment: @Thieuma I edited the question to adjust for your edit.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox By doing this I get "error C2864 : only static const integral data members can be initialized within a class"

Comment: @Thieuma, yep, without constexpr, you need to define the value of the string in a cpp file. I will update.

Answer (score 1):

Following this comment from the asker:

> I'm creating a list of keyword that I will looking for in a file and
>   then exchange the keyword with its value. ex: find the keyword
>   "$temperature" -> replace the word with "28°C"

The approach you are suggesting of using named variables, or an enum will be inappropriate for this since C++ has no reflection and variable names are not accessible from the code. What you want is a map - possibly `std::map<std::string, std::string>`, although higher performance options might be necessary depending on the use case - from the values you want to find to the values you want to replace them with.

The best way to do this would be to read in a file containing the replacement values because then you can modify the replacement values without modifying the code and have a more general solution, but you can otherwise use C++11's unified initialisation lists to populate the map in your code, or perhaps populate them one by one in, for example, a constructor, if unified initialisation isn't suitable for your needs or for some reason C++11 is unavailable to you.

You can then scan through the file finding strings you want to replace and replacing them with the listed replacement. Be careful though, what will you do about overlapping replacement? Do you only check whole words, etc?